# how to go from front suspension to full suspension?

Tags: suspension, frugal, front

I got a bike for my birthday, a cheap one, 200€ 27,5 with front suspension, but I want a full-suspension bike.  My question is: is it cheaper to buy a full-suspension frame and move the parts to the new frame, or buy a new bike?

Comment: Another option - if you haven't assembled the bike - it may be possible to do a return to the shop.  You'll need the sales receipt/docket though, and depending on locale you may only get store credit.   200 euro won't buy much of a full suspension bike, so you'll need to top it up with your own money to even get a BSO full sus.

Comment: Why do you want full suspension? Do you plan to do a lot of riding where that will actually be useful? If you're mostly riding on roads and cycle paths, full suspension is just a huge pile of extra weight to carry around and it saps your power by flexing as you pedal.

Comment: It's cheaper to buy a *used* bike.  Many perfectly serviceable bikes are sitting in garages, basements, and sheds, essentially unused.

Comment: I ride down stairs on my hard tail 29'er BSO, unsure how much difference your smaller wheels make.

Answer (score 1):

You have a "BSO" and as such is built down to a price.  A bare full-suspension frame will cost more than that whole bike, and no guarantee the parts will move over.

I suspect you're a teenager?    Your best bet is to just ride your new bike.  Develop endurance and leg power and aerobic capacity.  While you're riding, look at other riders and learn.

Even though you call it a "cheap bike" its still worth looking after.   Store it inside at night and not out in the rain.  Tune it up occasionally, and don't biff it around.   Lock it too.

In 3-5 years you can decide to replace it outright with something that you've saved up for - so budget to save 10 euros a week and in 3 years you'll have over 1500 euros to spend on the bike you want.  By then your legs should be fully grown so the current bike frame will be too small.

And be grateful that someone bought you a bike, even if its not exactly what you wanted.

Comment: 21 yo thats not my first bike the other broke
im grateful dude but my other bike broke cause i was riding and jumpin and go down stairs etc
so i thougth a fs was safer
thanks for your advice man

Comment: @RazzeT ok fair enough - you're "full sized" so you won't grow out of it.   A BSO won't like being ridden down stairs or any sort of stunting.  But at 21 you're an adult and can make your own decisions about how to treat your stuff.   The short answer is "if you want a full sus, buy a full sus"

Comment: The reason it broke is it was cheap not because it was a HT. A FS bike that can reliably handle that stuff riding style will start at about 1500€. If you can't afford that, you are much better to stick to a higher quality hard tail if that is the style riding you want to do.